# Alternative to MAXIFS function

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I currently only have access to excel 2016 for a certain contract, I need to replace this formula

=maxifs($C$2:$C,$A$2:$A,$E2,ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH($B$2:$B)),$G2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBYV1.png)

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*These formula works with Google Sheet, as well with all versions of Excel.*

- *You may try this:*

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$A$20=$E2)*($B$2:$B$20=$G2)*($C$2:$C$20)))
  ```
- *Or you may use this way also:*

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A:A=$E2)*(B:B=$G2)*(C:C)))
  ```

*You are trying wrong cell references `$A$2:$A`*

- *Or you may use try in this array ( CSE) forula also:*

  ```
  {=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$20=$E2,IF($B$2:$B$20=$G2,$C$2:$C$20)))}
  ```
- Finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*